Does dart stream buffers events when consumer is slower than producer?
Consider the following dart code:
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  await for (final val in incrementer()) {
    print(val);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}

Stream<int> incrementer() {
  int val = 0;
  final controller = StreamController<int>();
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (_) {
    controller.sink.add(val);
    val++;
  });
  return controller.stream;
}

We create a stream which emits every 500 milliseconds, but a consumer that consumes every one second (1000ms). Yet it seems that the consumer is able to catch all the emitted values:
0
1
2
3
4
...

Does this mean that the Dart runtime internally queues up emitted values?
If that is the case, then:

Is this behavior specific to await for? (i.e. does it happen in other cases like in stream.asyncMap)
If that's the case, is there any reason to use a StreamQueue because we already get queueing behavior from a vanilla stream?


"Does this mean that the Dart runtime internally queues up emitted values?", the buffering is done here: _BufferingStreamSubscription
